# How to get a reference to previous viewController in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

Can somebody help me get a reference of the previous `viewController` in the `UINavigationController` stack? I'm sure it's straight forward but I'm a bit tapped at the moment.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First thing array always starts with index 0, So to access previous you need to minus 2. Also the above code of your will crash with `Array index out of Range`, if your the index of access object is less than your count. so check your condition like this

```
let count = viewControllers?.count
if count > 1 {
    if let setVC = viewControllers?[count -2] as? SWSetVC {
        //Set the value
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 9):

## ⚠️  Keep in mind!

Although all answers above are working (partly) do not forget the following facts:

#### 1. Do NOT use `viewControllers[count - 1]`.

Accessing `index` directly may cause `⛔️ index out of range` error and crash your app! You can perform an existence check before that.

#### 2. Do NOT use use `count`! It could cause a performance hit!

Every time you call `someCollection.count > some number`, you are actually counting all element and it is possible to count hundreds of thousands elements just to check if it is not empty or it has at least some items.

> time complexity = O(n)

#### 3. Always remember to handle `else` condition of any `if` statement you write.

Leaving `else` state empty (like the answer by **Nirav D**) will very likely to put your app in an unhandled state.

---

## ✅ Simple safe and performant solution

Just start from the end of the array and look for the next controller after the `topViewController` with this extension:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    var previousViewController: UIViewController? { viewControllers.last { $0 != topViewController } }
}
```

> time complexity = O(1)

Comment: It's like a whole lesson! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 8):

You could also use this:

**Swift 5**

```
let i = navigationController?.viewControllers.firstIndex(of: self)
let previousViewController = navigationController?.viewControllers[i!-1]
```

**Swift 3**

```
 let i = navigationController?.viewControllers.index(of: self)
 let previousViewController = navigationController?.viewControllers[i!-1]
```

Answer (score 7):

I use this extension on my projects:

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element == UIViewController {

    var previous: UIViewController? {
        if self.count > 1 {
            return self[self.count - 2]
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

So you can check VCs in this way:

```
if self.navigationController?.viewControllers.previous is CustomVC {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I like to use the below function to get a reference to any `UIViewController` in the navigation stack. If there is no such reference it simply returns `nil`.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func getReference<ViewController: UIViewController>(to viewController: ViewController.Type) -> ViewController? {
        return viewControllers.first { $0 is ViewController } as? ViewController
    }
}
```

**Use Case:**

```
func tappedBackToHomeButton() {
    guard let homeVC = navigationController?.getReference(to: HomeVC.self) else { return }
    // Pass variables if needed.
    navigationController?.popToViewController(homeVC, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let count = self.navigationController.viewControllers.count;
self.navigationController.viewControllers[count - 2];
```

Comment: What happens to this code if there are less than three VCs in the navigation stack?

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 extension to get previous view controller

Extension:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    var previousViewController: UIViewController? {
        guard viewControllers.count > 1 else { return nil }
        return viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2]
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if let previousVC = self.navigationController?.previousViewController {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the previous controller is  `controllers[count - 2]`, not `controllers[count - 1]`.